# How to copy the file from Local to HDFS terminal which is running in EMR Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

How to copy file from local to the HDFS. There is no physical location of a file under the file , not even directory. I have 1 master node and 1 slave node in my cluster.

I used the command "hdfs dfs -put (Local file path) (HDFS file path)

[image: Link for Image]

Comment: There is no physical location of a file under the file , not even directory. --> This is unclear could you try and explain?

Comment: `There are 0 datanodes running`, so you don't have a working HDFS cluster to copy to

Comment: Instead of posting images of code and errors, please consider adding them as a code block to your question.